# Python 3, Basic Questions for building a library program (Beginner!)

Tags: python, python-3.x

For school I'm in the process of writing a program that acts as a kind of library of sorts, you can add books to the library as well as lend books, return books, search for books and so forth. At the moment I'm starting to finally see the light in the end of the tunnel and (atleast I thought..) I'm getting ready to wrap this all up.

But as I'm thinking I don't have any way to deal with if you add two books with the same title by the same author.. If its two books with the same title but from different authors it's no problem, but if they're by the same author I got a problem.. Basically how my "lend a book" function is working is that if there's a title that occurs more than once in the dictionary where I've stored everything you get to choose what book to lend by the name of the author, and then it loops through all these authors with an "if any(blablabla...)"-clausule, but since it loops through them one by one it always just ends up with the first instance of that book, if you understand what I mean.. and if that's already loaned the program just says "Sorry, that book is already loaned" and returns to the main menu.

Is there any clever way through this? Right now I'm reading in books and authors from a textfile and then, in every function, I put them in a dictionary with the titles as keys and the authors as a value to that key (in a list, so if there's more than one of a title the list holds all authors). Maybe there's a smarter way to do this as well? I'm just beginning to learn about classes, maybe I can solve it with classes somehow?

Anyhoooow, my main question is how I could work through my "several identical books from the same identical author" dilemma.. Really grateful for any help what so ever :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need other specific information about distinct copies of a given book/author, you could just have a count with each, indicating how many copies you have.  If you *do* have other information distinguishing those copies, you can use that info to tell them apart.